# my footer and line break element are above my images, and I don't know how that happened

Tags: html, css

```
<main >
        <hr class="top-line" />
        <!--this is the middle section of the webpage.
           all thee food and prices goes here-->
        <h2>candy flavores</h2>
        <p class="established">Est. 2022</p>
        <br />
        <section>
          <h2>shrooms</h2>
        <div class="image">
          <article>
            <a href="cherry.html">
              <img src="./img-mushroom/cherry.jpg" width: 20%;
               />
            </a>
            <p class="flavor">cherry mushroom</p>
            <p class="price">3.00</p>
          </article> 
           <article>
            <a href="sour-apple.html">
              <img src="./img-mushroom/sour-apple.jpg"
             /></a>
            <p class="flavor">sour apple mushroom</p>
            <p class="price">3.75</p>
          </article>
           <article>
            <a href="strawberry-lemon.html">
              <img src="./img-mushroom/strawberry-lemon.jpeg"
              /></a>
            <p class="flavor">strawberry lemon mushroom</p>
            <p class="price">3.50</p>
          </article>
         <article>
            <a href="grape.html"> <img src="./img-mushroom/grape.png"
              /></a>
            <p class="flavor">grape mushroom</p>
            <p class="price">4.00</p>
          </article>

          <article>
            <a href="blueberry.html">
              <img src="./img-mushroom/blueberry.png"
              /></a>
            <p class="flavor">blueberry mushroom</p>
            <p class="price">4.50</p>
          </article>

          <article>
            <a href="strawberry-pineapple.html">
              <img src="./img-mushroom/strawberry-pineapple.png"
              
              /></a>
            <p class="flavor">starberry pineapple mushroom</p>
            <p class="price">1.50</p>
            </article>

          <article>
            <a href="orange-mango.html">
              <img src="./img-mushroom/orange-mango.jpg"
              /></a>
            <p class="flavor">orange mango mushroom</p>
            <p class="price">2.75</p>
          </article></div>
        </section>
      
        </main>
        <hr/>
       <div id="footer"><!--footer color should be blue violit 
          and needs all social media links in it as well.-->
      <footer>
        <p class="address">123 candykingdom drive</p>
      </footer>
        </div>
```

I looked on w3school to find someone with a similar problem but there's nothing I've seen so far that's like what just happened.

on the webpage the footer and line break are above the images

I've tried looking at my css to see if that were the was the problem, but theirs's nothing written my css code that shows my footer going above my images

```
.image, img{/*gotta fix the height. the 
  footer is above my images for some 
  reason. */
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  
 
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  object-fit: fill;
   


}
footer {
  border: solid;
  font-size: 14px;
  width:100%;
  background-color: blueviolet;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Your `.image` has `height: 50px`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you got fixed height in your `.image, img { height:50px; }` style. Try to delete it or use `height: auto`.

Comment: it works, i put the width 50% and the height to auto. thank you.